# Sending packets via UDP in erlang

Tags: networking, erlang, erlang-ports

so i'm trying to send udp packet to a listening port on a computer which is not connected to the same LAN but has internet access via gen_udp in erlang.

I start my first node by opening the port 
(`{ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(8887).`) and the open the port on the other node the same way, When i send a packet from one node to the other via `gen_udp:send` i don't receive anything (trying flush() on the receiving node), So i'm wondering if there is something i'm doing wrong ? , i checked the firewalls and erlang and epmd is permitted.

Comment: is your receiving node also an erlang node ?

Comment: I suggest using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or some similar tool to see if the packet leaves the sending computer and arrives at the destination computer.

Comment: thx for the tip Adam :) , yeah i noticed that my router is behind the trouble as i get the routers local ip address (i get a ip address associated with my router) as my source on wireshark, i tried disconnecting it and just plug my ethernet cable directly from my broadband to my computer and it worked, i could look into to it further more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try setting the controlling process of the Socket as the current process via :
`gen_udp:controlling_process(Socket,Pid)` ?

You should then setup a receive loop and messages will be sent to you. The format of the messages should be : `{udp, Socket, IP, InPortNo, Packet}`

You could also try setting the socket to passive mode by using `inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, false}])` after you have opened it. After which you can use 'gen_udp:recv/3` to read from the socket.

Comment: thx for the reply, controlling_process didn't work for me, i can't figure out whats causing the trouble since the process should be listening to that port , i also tried inet:i() to see that its setup and the status is bound.

Comment: @Krewie: what is the need of gen_udp:recv then ?